# Azure API App with User Input

Tags: c#, azure, raspberry-pi, iot

I am creating Azure API App, later i'll use it as Azure Logic App Connector.

I have created one App and tested it as Azure Logic App Connector. All is working fine.

I have few parameters in API App, which i want to get from users who is using Connector. i.e. Connection String, Authorization Token. Like, if we use SMTP Connector, it will ask user to add Server Name, Port, etc.

Any idea how to give user interface in API App (for Connector use)? Feel free to ask me if you are confused about my question.

***SOLUTION:***

Finally i did it with Swagger UI. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

API app is intended to provide backend services to your application.

In order to provide frontend tools for your user you would need to create an application that supplied that data.

That frontend could be anything! from a script that queries the user directly to a website that manipulates the data before sending it on.

The simplest method could be a single HTML form that uses the API App endpoint as the post address you could host the HTML page on the pi (I'm presuming that's what your using from your tag) and let the user point a web browser to it.

Comment: I know that API App provides backend only and i need to create app or something for front end but how i can configure that app with API App + Logic App Connector? There should be particular element/or app for that, that's what my questions is.

Comment: I may be greatly misunderstanding your question - Are you asking if you can have your users directly interacting with a Logic App? Or for your front end app to get configuration information from your Logic App?

Comment: 1. I have create API app. 2. I will publish it and use it as Logic App connector. 3. while adding connector as action i want to give UI to user from where user can add some connection data. 4. Ultimately user will be from my organization only but i am trying to create dynamic connector which i can use for multiple logic apps.

Comment: Where do you want the UI to be hosted? Are you wanting that to be a part of the Logic App? (which it can't do) or is that external and simply communicating with the Logic App (which is the way it works)

Comment: It is not logic app UI. It is Logic App CONNECTOR UI. I want to give UI for CONNECTOR.

Comment: Basically i am creating logic app CONNECTOR (which can be achieve through API app only). The API App/CONNECTOR is ready but it has two field connection & password. Now, i want this two filed value from user. Like, if you add SMTP Connector to Logic App, it will ask you for few configuraiton i.e. server address, port, user,pass. hope you got it. it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: The only inputs available for Logic / API apps are either from external applications such as twitter / facebook etc or via a HTML Post. There is no UI for any part of Logic / API Apps. It is an API, it expects a JSON message with those details in. You need to build a front end that will send the relevant data into the Logic / API App.